# MOSFET On/Off Switch Power Dissipation

Tags: powermosfet

Basic setup: A battery is discharged using some lightbulbs wired in parallel. At various points throughout the discharge cycle, lightbulbs are switched off in order to increase the resistance of the load to slow the rate of discharge. I'd like to be able to easily switch the bulbs remotely/automatically.

MOSFETs would be triggered via voltage monitoring relays to switch the light bulbs off when required. The triggering voltage applied to the gate would come from a dedicated power supply, and would be completely independent of the discharge load. The MOSFETs would be either fully on or fully off at all times. Each bulb in the chain would get its own MOSFET. There would also be a "master MOSFET" that would be an on/off for the whole setup.

Suppose the resistance of the master MOSFET is listed as 1.05 Ω when it is on. The voltage of the battery is 250 V, the resistance of the bulbs was 150 Ω and thus the battery was discharging at about 1.6 A. How much power is the MOSFET dissipating?

Basically I'm just confused as to how or why MOSFETs would be required to dissipate much heat at all in this particular setup.

Here's what I'm looking at. I think I've properly upscaled for my application, but doing an Ohms Law calculation for 250 V and 1.05 Ω turns up a laughable result, so I'm obviously not running the right equation or else I'm looking at a very wrong component. Perhaps you'll spot some other red flag in this spec sheet I'm totally overlooking.

[image: The component I'm eyeing]

Answer (score 0):

\$(1.6 A)^2 * 1.05 \Omega = 2.7 W\$

The power is only ridiculously high, if you don't have the bulb in series.

Still consider that 2.7 W is still appreciable power and needs good cooling or a lower resistance MOSFET.

Also consider, that these MOSFETs have large gate charge. If you turn them on/off too slowly they will briefly dissipate 100s of Watts and can get destroyed in this instants.

E.g. it might have 100 Ohm resistance during the turn on phase. You now have 1 Amp flowing through it already dissipating 100 W.

Comment: Oh man I feel pretty dumb. Of course!

Comment: @DerekHershman We all do from time to time :)

Comment: @DerekHershman Yes. The formula for the power dissipation in a resistive element (MOSFET in this case) is always \$P=I^2\cdot R\$

Comment: What a brain fart. Thanks, tobalt. In general, the specs for these fets mean they should work just fine for my application, given a bit of cooling, yes?

Comment: @DerekHershman I just noticed that these are SMD MOSFETs. Yeah these can handle quite a bit of power because they can readily sink it into the PCB if you connected the drain pads with a big exposed pad and possibly some copper area around it. However a free standing (not-bolted) 3 leg through-hole part might burn at 2.7 W.

Comment: Yeah, at the ridiculously low cost i figured I'd just get the Cadillacs. I'm going to add cooling with some copper pipe and a spare CPU cooler for the bulbs anyway since this is all happening in the hatch of a Prius. I'll incorporate the Fets into the cooling scheme as well. But yeah, it appears these are rated for lot more power than they'll be seeing.

Comment: Consider also that a bulb resistance changes dramatically with the filament temperature. A cold filament can have a resistance almost one order of magnitude smaller than a hot filament. At turn on you can have a strong inrush current.

Comment: How strong of an inrush current are we talking? I have a circuit breaker rated for 6 amps that I believe is type c. Definitely some tolerance built in, but definitely not infinite. Enough of a concern that I should consider using 100w resistors instead of bulbs?